# Looking for a working CalDav Client

Tags: calendar, gnome-calendar, caldav

I've been scouring the internet and this forum for a good, working CalDav client so I can integrate my Fastmail calendar into my Ubuntu 20.04 desktop.  I know I can do a Google calendar, but I'm de-Googling my life and have been using Fastmail for several years.  I even have it logging into the Google accounts I can't get rid of so it's become my one-stop-shop calendar to see my entire life planned out.  The Online Accounts setting doesn't just have a CalDav setup as I had hoped it would, but it's got all the big tech integrations.  Of all the CalDav clients I've found, most are no longer in development.  Is there a way I can add a CalDav connection via Terminal that will integrate with the build in calendar?  Anything basically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer to my own question.  Lightning has been removed from the Thunderbird add-ons, but native Thunderbird can subscribe to an ics or CalDAV calendar.  I had to go one at a time to add my Fastmail calendars to Thunderbird since it doesn't support auto discovery.  Up until I stumbled onto this solution I had been staying logged into Fastmail in Firefox so I could use my calendar.

Answer (score -1):

I found Evolution to be a better fit (basically because it provides a .deb package instead of flatpak).

Comment: Thunderbird is packaged with Ubuntu, but I too generally prefer .deb packages over flatpak.  I tried Evolution for a bit but it just didn't suit my taste, and believe me I wanted to try anything over Thunderbird which is very 90's-esque.